# Variable to put into the append method of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I installed a module which is called Yahoo_fin, not Yahoo Finance. It allows me to return a dataframe with 1 ticker and the output look like this:

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe 1

df1 = si.get_data('AAPL', start_date = '30/10/2019' , end_date = '31/10/2019')
df1.head()

Output:
            open        high        adjclos     ticker
2019-10-30  61.189999   61.325001   60.302502   AAPL

# DataFrame 2

df2 = si.get_data('A', start_date = '30/10/2019' , end_date = '31/10/2019')
df2.head()

Output:
            open        high        adjclos     ticker
2019-10-30  34.189999   67.325001   60.302502   A

# DataFrame 3

df3 = si.get_data('GILD', start_date = '30/10/2019' , end_date = '31/10/2019')
df3.head()

Output:
            open        high        adjclos     ticker
2019-10-30  65.189999   87.325001   88.302502   GILD
```

I want to call 100 dataframes with different tickers and combine into 1 dataframe. The output look this this:

```
Output:
            open        high        adjclos     ticker
2019-10-30  61.189999   61.325001   60.302502   AAPL
2019-10-30  34.189999   67.325001   60.302502   A
2019-10-30  65.189999   87.325001   88.302502   GILD .....and so on
```

I followed the previous post and I create a blank dataframe and store all the dataframe values but I have no idea where should I put the Append method in the code. Please help me!

```
blank_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['open', 'high', 'adjclose', 'ticker'])
list = ['A', 'AAL', 'GILD']

for ticker in list:
blank_df = si.get_data(ticker, start_date = '30/10/2019' , end_date = '31/10/2019')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append each ticker to the blank df:

```
blank_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['open', 'high', 'adjclose', 'ticker'])
list = ['A', 'AAL', 'GILD']

for ticker in list:
    ticker_df = si.get_data(ticker, start_date = '30/10/2019' , end_date = '31/10/2019')
    blank_df = blank_df.append(ticker_df)
```

Comment: My pleasure :-)